# TCPDF and permalinks

Tags: posts, permalinks, pdf

I am currently using a post to pdf plugin 'Hacklog down as pdf' which works ok. I've used it before in a current working environment.

It suddenly stopped working but I have found out that when changing my permalink structure to the default '?p=5463', for example, it works perfectly.

It stops working when I switch back to the custom structure `/%category%/%postname%/`. Since I must keep it this way, I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how I might get around this problem.

I believe that since the plugins uses `/generate.php?id=5463` to generate pdfs it may be be expecting the id but in fact being passed the permalink structure causing the error.

Could a solution be with my .htaccess file? Ideas would be much appreciated!

**ERROR message:**

`No webpage was found for the web address:`

`../plugins/down-as-pdf/generate.php?id=35130`

`Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.`

Comment: Search for that path in the plugin source. If it is a relative path as it appears to be, make it an absolute one and see if that helps.

Comment: I think I'm also going to follow the trail for how `%category%` works. As it seems the plugin only fails when this exists. For now i'm just going to use `%postname%` as a temporary fix.